# Getting "waiting for www.adobe.com" when starting a flex application

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

Everytime I start my Flex application (as opposed to Air), Firefox is "waiting for www.adobe.com".
I am pretty sure that namespaces URL are not loaded, so why is Flex reaching out to adobe? Flash update?
I am using Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: Where do you see this "Waiting for www.adobe.com" text?

Comment: It's in the status bar at the bottom. As if a new page was being loaded in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your template.html file in the `html-template` folder. The default template inserts images that get loaded from adobe.com.

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='"
                    + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" );
</script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'>Get Adobe Flash player</a>" );
</script>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
</a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash Player</a>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I only found the first one in index.template.html . But it works wonders. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it depends on the template you are using. The second part is usually inside the `<noscript>` tags.